# Lagrange multipliers with inequality constraints.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the maximum of $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)^3$, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the following constraints:
>
> $x \ge 0,\ 3x+2y+z=1,\ z\ge x^2+y^2$

I know how to work with lagrange multipliers when the constraints are equalities(defining $h=f-\lambda_1 g_1-\lambda _2 g_2-...-\lambda_kg_k$ and solving $h=0$.But what am I suppose to do when the constraints are inequalities?

Comment: you can eliminate one variable

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Which one?How?

Comment: You should look up the KKT conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions?wprov=sfsi1

Comment: @Ture Isn't it possible to solve it with the usual ways of Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: @ChikChak: more or less, but KKT are the proper generalization to multiple constraints including inequalities.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Since  Inever heard of KKT,could you explain to me how to solve it using Lagrange Multipliers only?

Comment: This is actually very simple.  Just use Lagrange multipliers with the one equality constraint.  You will get multiple solutions.  Just pick the one that satisfies the inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which is a mixture of elimination and Lagrange.  Using the only constraint that's an equality, we can substitute $z = 1-3x-2y$ into the function and the other constraints.  So now the problem is to maximize
$$
    f(x,y) = (x+y+(1-3x-2y))^3 = (1-2x-y)^3
$$
subject to the constraints $x\geq 0$ and 
$$
    x^2 + y^2 \leq 1-3x-2y
$$
The first inequality describes the right half of the $xy$-plane.
Complete the square in the second inequality:
\begin{align*}
    x^2 + 3x + y^2 + 2y &\leq 1 \\
    x^2 + 3x + \frac{9}{4} + y^2 + 2y + 1 &\leq \frac{17}{4} \\
    \left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y + 1\right)^2  &\leq \frac{17}{4}
\end{align*}

Therefore, this inequality describes a disk of radius $\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$ centered at $\left(-\frac{3}{2},-1\right)$.  The two together form the constraint set.  It's the part that's shaded red and blue below.

[image: constraint set]

When looking for the extreme points, you want to search for ordinary critical points *inside* the constraint set, and constrained critical points *on the boundary* of the set.  For the first, we use the first-order conditions.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= -6(1-2x-y)^2 \\
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= -3(1-2x-y)^2 \\
\end{align*}
The only way both of these can be zero is if $1-2x-y=0$, or $2x+y = 1$.  This describes a line through $(0,1)$ and $(1/2,0)$, shown in green on the diagram below.  You can see it doesn't touch the constraint set at all.  So there are no unconstrained critical points to check.

The boundary of the constraint set includes two curves $x=0$ and $\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y + 1\right)^2  = \frac{17}{4}$.  First, use Lagrange to find any critical points along $x=0$.  We get
\begin{align*}
    -6(1-2x-y)^2 &= \lambda \\
    -3(1-2x-y)^2 &= 0 \\
     x&= 0
\end{align*}
The third and second equation tell us that $(1-y)^2 =0$, or $y=1$.  Again, this is outside the constraint set.  Next, use Lagrange with the second constraint equation:
\begin{align*}
    -6(1-2x-y)^2 &= 2\lambda \left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right) \\
    -3(1-2x-y)^2 &= 2\lambda \left(y + 1\right)  \\    
    \left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y + 1\right)^2  &= \frac{17}{4}
\end{align*}
The first two equations tell us that $\lambda (2x+3) = \lambda(4y+4)$, so either $\lambda = 0$ (this forces $1-2x-y=0$, which has already been ruled out) or
\begin{align*}
    2x+3 &= 4y+4 \\
    y &= \frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
This line, shown in orange below, does intersect the boundary of the constraint set in two places: $\left(0,-\frac{1}{4}\right)$ (when $x=0$) and $\left(\sqrt{\frac{17}{5}}-\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{17}{5}} - 1\right)$.

Finally, because this constraint set is not smooth but has corners, we have to include those in our check points.  They occur when $x=0$ and $\left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y + 1\right)^2  = \frac{17}{4}$, or $\left(0,-1 \pm \sqrt{2}\right)$.

[image: constraint set with two lines]

So, four points to check:

- $x=0$, $y=-1 + \sqrt{2}$: $f=(2-\sqrt(2))^3 \approx 0.20101$
- $x=0$, $y=-1 - \sqrt{2}$: $f=(2+\sqrt(2))^3 \approx 39.799$
- $x=0$, $y=-\frac{1}{4}$: $f=\frac{125}{64} \approx 1.95313$
- $x=\sqrt{\frac{17}{5}}-\frac{3}{2}$, $y=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{17}{5}} - 1$, $f\approx 0.059423$

The greatest of these values by far is the one at $\left(0,-1-\sqrt{2}\right)$.  This is pretty messy, so I'm not 100% confident in the calculations, but [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=maximum+of+(1-2x-y)%5E3+subject+to+x+%E2%89%A5+0+and+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%E2%89%A4+1-3x-2y) agrees on the maximum.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much.One question-What if we did find some critical points at the beginning that touches the constraints?We simply had just to check it with the later points?

Comment: That's right; you just add them to the list.  This process is just KKT without the notation.